# How to update preload data in spring when DB record updated

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate

I use Spring and Hibernate for my application and want to load some configuration data from DB when the application launches. But the question is how I can update the preloaded data in case the record in DB is updated (btw, I use mysql for the DB).

I found some solutions said using the trigger in mysql, but I don't know whether the trigger can call some WebService all send some events to tell the application.

Are there some more solutions or good ideas for the case?

Here's the sample code of preloading data:

```
@Service  
public class PreloadService {

@Autowired
private ConfigurationDao configurationDao; 

private Map<String, String> preloadConfs = null;

@PostConstruct
public void getConfigurations() {
    Map<String, String> results = new HashMap<String, String>();
    List<Configuration> confs = configurationDao.findConfigurations(null, null);
    for (Configuration c: confs) {
        results.put(c.getCode(), c.getDescription());
    }
    preloadConfs = results;
}

public String getDescription(String code) {
    return preloadConfs.get(code);
}
```

}

and other class should use the class like this

```
@Autowired
private PreloadService preloadService;

public void foo() {
    preloadService.getDescription("code");
}
```

So the question is how I can update the preloadConfs object if the configuration table was changed?

Comment: show us some code, especially the loading of config and the data structures used

Comment: I've updated my question and added some code FYI.

Comment: Have a look [here](http://vladmihalcea.com/2014/08/29/how-to-customize-hibernate-dirty-checking-mechanism/) to customize dirty checking in Hibernate. Also look [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/caching/) to make use of Spring's  `@Cacheable` to improve perfomrance. **P.S.** Consider removing `@PostConstruct` and modify `getDescription` accordingly.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll read the refs carefully.